# Concept of <ALL> type in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate, ansi-sql

Obviously every SQL dialect has the concept of `NULL`. However, I'm wondering if any support the concept of an `ALL` type? Let me give one example where I think it's quite useful:

```
SELECT content_type_id, count(*) FROM movies
GROUP BY content_type_id WITH ROLLUP
```

```
content_type_id count(*)
NULL            1
Movie           45014
Movie Bundle    865
Other           62
TV Series       66
NULL            151984      # this should be our ALL value
```

Now, I know that there is the [`GROUPING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_grouping) function which can be for. From the MySQL docs:

> For GROUP BY queries that include a WITH ROLLUP modifier, the ROLLUP operation produces super-aggregate output rows where NULL represents the set of all values. The GROUPING() function enables you to distinguish NULL values for super-aggregate rows from NULL values in regular grouped rows.

However, this seems a bit hackish and it sounds like it'd be much more appropriate to just have an `ALL` value, especially if there are multiple levels of aggregation, where it becomes quite tedious to keep track of! Does something like that existing in SQL?

---

**Update**: any SQL dialect is fine. I'm curious more in a general sense if any db's have this concept or the sql standard itself.

Comment: Edited to remove the [tag:sql-server] tag.

Comment: @BillKarwin I removed all the specific db tags. I'm wondering more in general if this concept exists in either the ANSI standard or any particular implementation.

Comment: @AaronBertrand updated to remove all tags.

Comment: `NULL` is not the opposite of `ALL`. `NULL` is synonym of missing, unrecovered data that does actually exist. And, relational algebra -- the initial core of SQL -- does not model the concept of aggregation either; that means there's no concept of "all" in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no value in SQL that means "ALL." But if it bothers you to have a NULL in the grouping column in the query you show, you can do this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(content_type_id, 'ALL') AS content_type_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM movies
GROUP BY content_type_id WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 0):

`especially if there are multiple levels of aggregation, where it becomes quite tedious to keep track of`

If you just want to do this, you can use ‘union all’, which is simpler and compatible with all sql dialects

```sql
SELECT content_type_id, count(*) FROM movies
GROUP BY content_type_id 
union all
SELECT 'all', count(*) FROM movies
```

The 'all' operator exists in some dialects such as Oracle. I think this is a very bad syntax, because it is likely to hide the intent of SQL. But it might be different from what you think?

```sql
select 1 from dual where 3 > all(1, 2, 3)
```